# How To add a gridview to Datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I want to have a grid view like this image
[image]

I find out that I should have a `gridview` in `datagridview` cell so I tried to find how to do that.I finally find that there is not any `DataGridViewcolumn` type like `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and etc,So I think I must create a custom `Datagridview` Column..But I don't know how to create..I found this tutorial 
[Tutorial](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0707061)
It is about creating a custom cell but I need a grid.I don't know which class should I override in my custom column.Can you please help me find out how to fix my problem?
Here is my code

```
public class DataGridViewGridColumn :
    DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public DataGridViewGridColumn()
        {
        }

        public DataTable  Dt;
        private bool needsRecalc = true;

        public class DataGridViewBarGraphCell :
          DataGridViewCell
        {
//Do I need to override  Paint()?
            protected override void Paint()

        }

        public void CalcMaxValue()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SourceGrid`. You can download from [here.](http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/)